# AngularJS application halt IE10 browser to crash

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I have been experiencing weird behavior with AngularJS. When I run AngularJS on IE10 my browser become crashed, I have seen my windows processor monitoring it some how multiply memory x time greater with loop and at some stage my browser become halt.

Please advice anything I can do with that.

Thanks

Comment: What application are you running ? Do you have an example ? It must have something to do with the code.

Comment: Can you provide your piece of Code Shakeeb Beta ?

Comment: @Xorsat I will porivde complete codebase sir ;p

Comment: @lechariotdor actually yes I will provide you link of application privately if possible can I have your email address?

Comment: give us the link too - we would want to help if possible

Comment: @MSK It's not only for me, it's for all people out there who wants to help you, but cannot because there isn't any code to work on ;) If it's something you don't want to share publicly, maybe try to isolate a page/partial/part of your app where it happens (a plunker would be nice) so people here can work on it.

Comment: Thanks you all , I have resolve this issue actually there is a problem with window.href = '/somelink' and I have changed with angularjs $location service